# Справится ли C# с управлением другой программы

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, visual-c++, vb.net

- Справится ли C# с управлением другой программы?
- Насколько он хуже или лучше чем C++ в этом плане?
- Справится ли с этой задачей VB.NET?

Требуется.

1. Изменить размеры окна стороннего приложения.
2. Отправить приложение на самый нижний Z уровень, чтобы оно не
   появлялось поверх других открытых окон, в то время когда на нем
   будут    происходить какие то действия, например нажатия кнопок.
3. Требуется выбирать в выпадающем списке нужный пункт и далее нажимать
   кнопку для применения настроек.

Понимаю что это все можно сделать через WinApi но не понимаю где взять описания функций (желательно на русском) и как их встраивать в код C#.
Например, как это делалось в VB 6.0 помню.

Comment: Описание функций WinAPI ищите в MSDN

Comment: @dlm0n чтобы ответить на этот вопрос c++ знать не нужно, сомнительная правка, особенно учитывая возраст вопроса. ИМХО.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- c# справится. Справится любой язык умеющий вызывать winapi
- Хуже только тем, что нужно объявить функции winapi и возможно структуры
- у vb те же возможности, что и у c#

Вам сюда http://www.pinvoke.net/ за тем как объявлять функции winapi в c# и vb.net

Возможно подойдет что-то более высокоуровневое вроде Cruciatus от 2GIS

Answer (score 30):

Для вашей задачи вполне подойдёт стандартный майкрософтовский UI Automation. Вот пример без P/Invoke:

```
var notepadProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault();
var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(notepadProcess.MainWindowHandle);
var transformPattern = (TransformPattern)window.GetCurrentPattern(TransformPattern.Pattern);
transformPattern.Resize(300, 300);
```

(изменяет размер окна notepad.exe на 300х300).

Не забудьте подключить сборки `UIAutomationClient` и `UIAutomationTypes` и добавить контроль ошибок.

В MSDN есть документация об остальной функциональности UI Automation. Например, [как активировать контрол](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747211%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (нажать на кнопку, выбрать пункт меню и т. п.).

Список всех подокон и их доступных свойств легко подсмотреть при помощи утилиты [Inspect.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) из Windows SDK.

---

После небольшого упражнения в гуглопоиске на стэковерфлоу, вот более серьёзный пример:

```
// находим бегущий notepad
var notepadProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault();
var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(notepadProcess.MainWindowHandle);
// меняем размер окна
window.GetPattern<TransformPattern>().Resize(300, 300);

// получаем старый текст    
var edit = window.FirstChildByType(ControlType.Document);
TextPattern textPattern = edit.GetPattern<TextPattern>();
var oldText = textPattern.DocumentRange.GetText(-1);

// заменяем его на новый. для этого придётся посылать нажатия на клавиатуру
// основано на этом примере: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750582.aspx
textPattern.DocumentRange.Select();
edit.SetFocus();
Thread.Sleep(100);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{DEL}");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(
    "Тормозите прямо в папу. Папа мягкий. Он простит.");

// сохраним изменённый файл под новым именем
// вызовем File -> Save as... (на русскоязычной системе понадобятся другие строки!)
var menuBar = window.FirstChildByType(ControlType.MenuBar);
var fileMenu = menuBar.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(ControlType.MenuItem, "File");
// раскрыли меню File:
fileMenu.GetPattern<ExpandCollapsePattern>().Expand();
Thread.Sleep(100);

// нашли пункт Save As
var saveAsMenu = fileMenu.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(ControlType.MenuItem, "Save As...");
// и выполнили его
saveAsMenu.GetPattern<InvokePattern>().Invoke();
Thread.Sleep(100);

// запомнили элемент с фокусом, это edit box для ввода имени файла
var saveAsEditBox = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;

// поменяем ещё кодировку через комбобокс Encoding
// нашли окно:
var saveAsDialog = AutomationHelpers.FindWindowFrom(saveAsEditBox);
// и комбобокс
var encodingCombobox =
    saveAsDialog.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(ControlType.ComboBox, "Encoding:");
// раскрыли его:
encodingCombobox.GetPattern<ExpandCollapsePattern>().Expand();

// нашли пункт UTF-8 и выбрали его:
var utf8item =
    encodingCombobox.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(ControlType.ListItem, "UTF-8");
utf8item.GetPattern<SelectionItemPattern>().Select();

// вернули фокус в edit box
saveAsEditBox.SetFocus();
Thread.Sleep(100);

// послали название файла и Enter
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{%}TEMP{%}\oster.txt{ENTER}");
```

В коде используется следующий простой хелпер:

```
static class AutomationHelpers
{
    static public T GetPattern<T>(this AutomationElement element)
        where T : BasePattern
    {
        var pattern = (AutomationPattern)typeof(T).GetField("Pattern").GetValue(null);
        return (T)element.GetCurrentPattern(pattern);
    }

    static public AutomationElement FirstChildByType(
        this AutomationElement element, ControlType ct)
    {
        return element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ct));
    }

    static public AutomationElement FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(
        this AutomationElement element, ControlType ct, string name)
    {
        return element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Descendants,
            new AndCondition(
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ct),
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, name)));
    }

    static public AutomationElement FindWindowFrom(AutomationElement control)
    {
        var walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
        while (control.Current.ControlType != ControlType.Window)
            control = walker.GetParent(control);
        return control;
    }
}
```

---

VB.NET справится точно так же, функциональность UI Automation доступна в обоих языках.

---

Добавил паузы в секунду между действиями и адаптировал к русской системе (другие названия пунктов меню), результат:

[image: большая анимашка]

Comment: насколько у WinApi в этом плане богаче возможности по сравнению с UI Automation ?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, кое-чего UI Automation не умеет, но я подробное сравнение не проводил. Например, с UI Automation вы не можете засабклассить чужое окно. Но зато с WinAPI вы не сможете так легко нажать на WPF-овскую кнопку (хотя наверняка как-нибудь можно).

Comment: Аналогичная (или очень похожая) вещь есть в jscript (или точнее в ActiveX WSchipt.Shell).

Comment: @nick_n_a: Интересно, не знал.