# Как и на каком языке можно написать программу, которая автоматизирует ручное заполнение информации в окне браузера

Tags: javascript, python, windows, vba, автоматизация

Текущий неавтоматизированный процесс выглядит следующим образом:

1. Нужно зайти в браузер и открыть специальную ссылку;
2. Нужно выбрать из выпадающего списка свой логин;
3. Выбрать папку с файлами и сами файлы, которые будут загружаться;
4. Дальше для каждого окошка появляются формы для заполнения, например: первый файл называется `Автор - Книга.doc`, под этим название есть две формы для заполнения: "Автор: "; "Книга";
5. Руками копируется "Автор" в форму для заполнения; руками копируется "Книга" в форму для заполнения - так для каждого отдельного загружаемого файла;
6. После того как все формы с "Авторами" и "Книгами" заполнены нажимается кнопка "Загрузить";
7. По результатам загрузки появляется окно "Загрузка завершена": "Автор - Книга".... и эту информацию нужно скопировать, например, в эксель файл.

Вопрос: можно ли написать программу, которая автоматизирует этот процесс - чтобы она сама заполняла формы по стандартизированному название (между автором и книгой всегда могут стоять "пробел дефис пробел); чтобы копировала и заносила информацию в эксель; чтобы, перемещала загруженные файлы из одной папки в другую.

Из навыков программирования только VBA excel. Хочется также понять, что конкретно и в каких языках программирования стоит изучить, чтобы суметь сделать подобную программу. Предпочтительно на Python. И был бы очень признателен за ответы на то, как решить последовательные кусочки этой довольной большой задачи и где можно прочитать ответы, чтобы эти кусочки работали: как заполнять формы в браузере, используя имя файла "Автор - Книга.doc" над этими формами? Как выбирать логин из списка? и др.

Comment: UI Automation вполне справится. C#. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Interact with other programs using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14288177/4279)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Есть множество систем автоматизации тестирования ПО. Они не очень распространены в миру в силу того, что специфичны для профессии QA-engineer, но с такими задачами они справляются на раз. Есть системы которые лучше работают с web, с мобильными, с десктопными. Примеры - Uppium, Selenium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы пытаться повторить действия пользователя с GUI буквально, можно взглянуть на задачу глазами программиста:

- вместо открытия браузера, заполнения и отправки формы, можно выполнить http POST запрос напрямую (`request.post()`)
- вместо выбора файлов в графическом диалоге, можно использовать API, которое возвращает список файлов по шаблону (`Path().glob("*.doc")`)
- вместо копирования руками метаданных книги из названия файла `Author - Title.doc` в элементы формы, выставляются требуемые параметры запроса напрямую (author, title  в примере). Сами метаданные из имени файла можно получить, манипулируя строку с именем напрямую: `fn.split('-')` или с помощью регулярных выражений: `r'^([^-]+?)\s*-\s*(.+)\.doc$'`
- вместо копирования результатов загрузки из окна в Excel, ответ сервера напрямую печатается в csv формате в стандартный вывод (`csv.writer(sys.stdout)`) Что легко в файл скопировать (`| tee -a books.csv`)

Конечный скрипт, который загружает файлы с книгами, может выглядеть так:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''Upload "<author> - <title>.doc" books from the given directory.

Usage: upload-books <dir-path> | tee -a books.csv
'''
import csv
import re
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import requests # $ pip install requests

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__)

src_dir = sys.argv[1]
with requests.Session() as sess:
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    for path in Path(src_dir).glob('*.doc'):  # for each book
        metadata = re.findall(r'^([^-]+?)\s*-\s*(.+)\.doc$', path.name)
        if not metadata:
            print("warning: can't find author, title in path:", path,
                  file=sys.stderr)
            continue # don't upload

        # upload book
        author, title = metadata[0]
        book = {path.name: (path.name, path.open('rb'), 'application/msword'), 
                'author': author, 'title': title}    
        r = sess.post('https://example.com/api/v1/books', files=book,
                      auth=('user', 'passwd'))
        if not r.ok:
            print("warning: can't upload book from path:", path, file=sys.stderr)
            continue # don't save book info

        # save uploaded book info
        data = r.json()['response']
        writer.writerow([str(path), author, title, data['url']])
```

Это в хорошем  случае, когда у сайта есть явное API или спонтанно сформировавшийся набор http запросов/ответов, не требует выполнения динамического кода в браузере (или когда результаты этого выполнения могут быть легко смоделированы).

В менее удачном случае, когда, например, за загрузку книг ответчает Silverlight control, который использует какой-нибудь свой протокол для общения с сервером, то может быть проще использовать инструменты GUI автоматизации такие как [pywinauto, pyautogui](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings) или [AutoIt (упомянутый в ответе на схожий вопрос на Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14288361/4279).

В промежуточном случае, интерфейс реализован в браузере на javascript и работу с ним можно автоматизировать, используя что-нибудь вроде [Selenium WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) (+
 [headless chrome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044)).

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее распространенным средством для таких целей является [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html).
Например, для формы с полями name, age и town команда должна вроде такой:

```
curl -d Name="HarryP" -d Age="123" -d Town="DefaultCity" -d Form_Submit="Send" http://www.example.com/process-form.php
```