# Имитация нажатия кнопки на сайте. Python

Tags: html, python, парсер, requests, bs4

Всем привет. Есть задача спарсить сайт, одна из опций - номер телефона клиента.
Но номер телефона изначально скрыт, и выглядит это примерно вот так:

```
<div class="object-builder-phone" blst="true">+7 495 626-...</div>
```

Далее - кнопка:

```
<div class="toggle-button" id="show-phone_button" blst="313548" lst1="313548" lst="0">Показать телефон</div>
```

При нажатии на нее появляется телефон и у его `div` в параметре `blst` ставится значение `false`

**Вопрос:**

Как **симитировать** нажатие на эту кнопку? Использую [python](/questions/tagged/python) [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) [bs4](/questions/tagged/bs4)

Comment: Если вы парсите и получаете исходный html с номером телефона, то какая разница отображается он в этом html или нет?

Comment: @retorta при парсинге телефон скрыт, так как показано в записи

Comment: Если он присутствует в html, которую вы получаете, то он уже имеется и всё хорошо, а если он не присутствует в исходной странице, то ищите каким запросом он подгружается и выполняйте этот запрос для получения телефона.

Comment: @retorta нажав на эту кнопку отправляется: "addphoneclick?id=141492840" методом post. Но я не знаю как получить новый html в котором телефон полностью присутствует.

Comment: Тогда моделируйте этот запрос и берите номер телефона из его ответа. Да, чтобы спарсить пользователя вам придётся сделать один запрос к основной его странице, а также один запрос, чтобы узнать телефон. Зачем вам новая html? Соберите необходимые данные по частям.

Comment: @retorta Из этого кода:
r = requests.post('http://www.realestate.ru/special/addphoneclick?id=141492840').text
 Я получаю только "OK" и все, как составить запрос чтобы узнать телефон?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это происходит на нужном вам сайте. Разберитесь с тем, каким запросом номер телефона таки получается на клиент. И обрабатывайте этот запрос, но имитации браузера и нажатия - это, вероятно, совсем не то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @retota подумаю над этим. Спасибо вам за ответы)

Comment: юзайте selenium для парсинга сторонних сайтов, проще будет(я вам по опыту говорю)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044) и [Как и на каком языке можно написать программу, которая автоматизирует ручное заполнение информации в окне браузера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518660/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увидел знакомое название атрибутов и т.к. одно время игрался с таким, то [кое-что осталось](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/0524cc422d0f00fd5b576c68fc05a4646b7a57ee/requests_example/get_phone__from__realestate.py#L25).

Судя по атрибутам, я знаю что за сайт (или его подобие) и предполагаю что для получения номера телефона, который скрыт, сайт никакие запросы не посылает, а хранит номер телефона скрыто – в атрибутах, таких как: `blst` и `lst1`.

Сам алгоритм получения номера находится в javascript страницы сайта, но его не сложно [переписать](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/0524cc422d0f00fd5b576c68fc05a4646b7a57ee/requests_example/get_phone__from__realestate.py#L7):

```
import math

def decrypt_phone(clipped_phone, value):
    decrypt = value / 17

    p1 = int(math.floor(decrypt / 100))
    p2 = int(decrypt - 100 * p1)
    t1 = str(p1)[1:] + '-' + str(p2).zfill(2)

    return clipped_phone.replace("...", "") + t1
```

Берем пример автора и подставляем значения:

```
clipped_phone = '+7 495 626-...'
value = 313548
print(decrypt_phone(clipped_phone, value))
```

Получаем:

```
+7 495 626-84-44
```

Comment: Уже год руки не доходили выложить решение, спасибо, примерно так и делал) Алгоритм получения номера действительно находился в js-скриптах

Answer (score 1):

Открой браузером, там есть консолька и история запросов http. Посмотри все запросы и ответы. Скорее всего телефон прилетает аяксом. На некоторых страницах даже не нужно загружать html для получения номера, а на некоторых аякс просто так не запросить.

В лучшем случае вы получите ответ json, в худшем b.soup прийдется менять на gecko или webkit и исполнять весь яваскипт там.

Также при использовании движка браузера будет возможность програмно кликать по кнопкам и ссылкам.

Comment: PhantomJS можно использовать через Selenium для автоматических действий со страницей

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", params={"did":123, "ng":456})
```