# Не получается нажать на кнопку в другом приложении

Tags: c#, winapi

Делаю приложение-кликер, которое будет закрывать окна с ошибкой в приложении, установленном на ПК. Приложение работает, окно с ошибкой находит, находит кнопку "ОК", которую требуется нажать, но не получается, собственно, нажать эту кнопку.

Смотрел код на pinvoke.net, брал оттуда примеры, но так ничего и не выходит.
Нажатие пытаюсь сделать через `SendMessage`.

`appHandle` - это окно, где надо нажать кнопку, оно отыскивается, все правильно
`children[0].ToString()` - это сама кнопка, она тоже отыскивается правильно

Посоветуйте варианты решения проблемы? Как правильно отправлять нажатие левой кнопкой мыши на кнопку в окне приложения?

```
 SendMessage(appHandle, BM_CLICK,WM_LBUTTONDOWN, children[0].ToString());
```

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509662/10105

Comment: нужно ни только нажать кнопку, но и отпустить ее.