# Как с помощью скрипта имитировать нажатие кнопок C#?

Tags: c#

У меня скрипт выделяет сам текст на определённом сайте, и надо, чтобы этот выделенный текст копировался в буфер обмена. Как с помощью кода нажать <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>? Работаю в Visual Studio, C#.

Comment: С этим прекрасно справится UI Automation. Вот вам [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105).

Answer (score 1):

```
text = document.selection.createRange().text;
Clipboard.SetText(text);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что данная задача решается через WinApi.

Например, вот тут пример на C++

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295677/winapi-c-simulate-button-clicked-with-window-handle

Но на C# не много отличий будет...