# Как получить список/окно(?) AutomationElement?

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть программа, написанная на .net.

> Меню программы:

[image]

Как можно получить список этих елементов?

> В AutomationTree меню не имеет детей:

[image]

Код:

```
void getChildrenNodes(AutomationElement aElement, TreeNode mainNode)
{
    AutomationElementCollection aEColl = aElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
    foreach (AutomationElement item in aEColl)
    {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(getElementText(item));
        mainNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        getChildrenNodes(item, childNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что для появления child-элементов меню нужно раскрыть.

У меня работает вот такой код:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(name).FirstOrDefault();
var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);

// вызовем Файл -> Выход (на англоязычной системе понадобятся другие строки!)
var menuBar = window.FirstChildByType(ControlType.MenuBar);
var fileMenu = menuBar.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(ControlType.MenuItem, "Файл");
// раскрыли меню File:
fileMenu.GetPattern<ExpandCollapsePattern>().Expand();
// подождём, пока меню раскроется реально
Thread.Sleep(100);

// нашли пункт Выход
var exitMenu = fileMenu.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(ControlType.MenuItem, "Выход");
// и выполнили его
exitMenu.GetPattern<InvokePattern>().Invoke();
Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Вспомогательный класс (взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105)):

```
static class AutomationHelpers
{
    static public T GetPattern<T>(this AutomationElement element)
        where T : BasePattern
    {
        var pattern = (AutomationPattern)typeof(T).GetField("Pattern").GetValue(null);
        return (T)element.GetCurrentPattern(pattern);
    }

    static public AutomationElement FirstChildByType(
        this AutomationElement element, ControlType ct)
    {
        return element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ct));
    }

    static public AutomationElement FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(
        this AutomationElement element, ControlType ct, string name)
    {
        return element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Descendants,
            new AndCondition(
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ct),
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, name)));
    }

    static public AutomationElement FindWindowFrom(AutomationElement control)
    {
        var walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
        while (control.Current.ControlType != ControlType.Window)
            control = walker.GetParent(control);
        return control;
    }
}
```