# Нажать на кнопку в стороннем приложении, используя WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi

Здравствуйте.
вкратце.
Нужно на c# и winapi реализовать данное сообщение

> "WM_PARENTNOTIFY fwEvent:WM_LBUTTONDOWN xPos: 386 yPos:227"

`Handle` мне известен, осталось разобраться с командой

а теперь подробно.
У сторонней программы есть поле (допустим 500х500) и в нём посередине кнопка, на которую мне необходимо нажать с помощью winapi.
Я смотрел через SPY++ и Ranorex, и они мне показывают кнопку и поле одним хэндлом.

Пробую для начала по полученному Handle отправить даблклик(есть такая функция, окно переходит в режим fullscreen)

```
PostMessage(winCanvas, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, (IntPtr)1, IntPtr.Zero);
```

И оно срабатывает корректно. Замечательно, теперь надо реализовать клик по середине экрана.

Изучая через SPY++ программу смог найти "сообщение" которое получает программа во время клика по кнопке.
Вот оно: `WM_PARENTNOTIFY fwEvent:WM_LBUTTONDOWN xPos: 386 yPos:227`.

Нагуглил, что это можно отправить клик по координатам через `MAKELPARAM`
Вот код, который я пробовал реализовать

```
private int MAKELPARAM(Point coord)
{
    int p = coord.X;
    int p_2 = coord.Y;
    return ((p_2 << 16) | (p & 0xFFFF));
}
```

//это я нахожу X,Y в который надо кликнуть

```
Point coordButton = new Point (this.Location.X + (this.Width / 2), this.Location.Y + (this.Height / 2));
```

//сама команда

```
PostMessage(winCanvas, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)MAKELPARAM(coordButton));
```

Буду рад объяснению решения моей проблемы/ошибки.
скриншоты:
окна с кнопкой http://s017.radikal.ru/i419/1611/27/d4e7584e71bd.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отрезок из SPY++ http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1611/6a/37fab16219f6.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И пожалуйста, ответы на c#.

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Вот вам [пример с UI Automation](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105), никакого P/Invoke не нужно.

Comment: не разобрался)) наверно просто устал за сегодня
по win api бы кто объяснил, а то я методом тыка делаю, а понять природу не могу

Comment: А что просто WM_LBUTTONCLICK не годится? Чтобы клик засчитался, нужно после BUTTONDOWN ещё и BUTTONUP, а  BUTTONCLICK выдаёт уже готовый клик.

Comment: в шарпе и winapi я вижу только WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK (дабл клик), то что вы мне советуете я не вижу на том же MSDN

Comment: Про WM_LBUTTONCLICK может и ошибся, может и нет его совсем. А вот UP точно нужен. Сами же замечали, что если нажать кнопку (DOWN) и держать, не отпуская, ничего не происходит. А если увести при этом с кнопки, то UP сработает на другом окне и тоже ничего не произойдёт. Клика нет ни здесь, ни там.

Comment: Хорошо, я вас понял
При тесте я используд давн и ап)) всё равно код не срабатывает

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл причину, почему код не работал.

неправильно:

```
Point coordButton = new Point (this.Location.X + (this.Width / 2), this.Location.Y + (this.Height / 2));
```

правильно:

```
Point coordButton = new Point(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
```

И вот, рабочий код нажатия кнопки:

```
PostMessage(winCanvas, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)1, MakeDWord(coordButton.X, coordButton.Y));
PostMessage(winCanvas, WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)1, MakeDWord(coordButton.X, coordButton.Y));
```