# Можно ли программным образом взаимодействовать с интерфейсом программы?

Tags: java, c#, gui, авторизация, интерфейс

Есть приложение с GUI, которое написано на JAVA.

Можно ли программным образом взаимодействовать с интерфейсом программы?

Например, находить элементы на форме, что-то вставлять в TextBox, затем нажимать на кнопки.

Или на таком высоком уровне нельзя ничего сделать и придется точно знать, где находится элемент и двигать курсор руками?

Какими программами можно исследовать интерфейс запущенного приложения?

Можно ли из C# взаимодействовать с приложением на JAVA?

Comment: Можно, конечно. Сейчас найду пример, пробегал тут когда-то.

Comment: Вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105

Comment: @VladD, а получить названия контролов можно через Inspect?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _названием_ контроллов?

Comment: @Grundy, что бы нажать на кнопку программно, я же должен знать как она называется?

Comment: powershell....?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, там не название, а текст. Текст можно прочитать даже глазами.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на системы атоматизированного тестирования приложений. [Годная статья про них.](https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/automation-of-desktop-applications/) 
Их великое множество, есть дорогие, есть опенсорсные, под разные платформы, и т.д. Самые известные

- MS Coded UI - для десктоп-приложений
- Selenium (для web-приложений)
- Appium (для мобильных приложений)

Все они основаны на неких скриптовых макро-языках, и одна из главных задач этих макро-команд - попадать якобы-мышкой в элементы управления, вводить текст, выбирать опции из списков и так далее, то есть эмулировать работу реальных пльзователей.

Идентифицируют элементы управления эти системы по разному:

- фиксируют их абсолютные и/или относительные пиксельные координаты
  (скрипты в итоге нужно разрабатывать под каждый размер экрана)
- знают идентификаторы - в web-формах оно как бы и есть
- распознают по скриншоту - текстовая метка, или соседние элементы, или
  надпись на кнопке, и т.д.

Если исследуемая программа уже существует и не меняется в процессе эксплуатации - скрипт нужно написать 1 раз, он будет разворачивать программу на полный экран и отлично попадать даже не зная названий элементов управления (по координатам).

Если же программа интенсивно меняется (особенно в части UI) - скрипты автоматизации QA резко теряют ценность, правильным является вопрос об их актуальности вообще до стабилизации UI.

Comment: MS Coded UI-тесты вполне себе умеют использовать Automation ID тоже.