# Открытие файла из кода неассоциированной программой

Tags: c#

Как открыть файл из кода на C# через неассоциированную с данным типом программу (то есть стороннюю)? Например, мне нужно из программы открыть файл "c:\1.pdf" программой "c:\program.exe", с которой работать так не получается: `Process.Start("c:\program.exe", "c:\1.pdf");` или `Process.Start("c:\program.exe c:\1.pdf");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему,

```
Process.Start(@"c:\program.exe", @"c:\1.pdf");
```

(обратите внимание на `@`).

При этом программа `c:\program.exe` должна, разумеется, поддерживать передачу файлов в командной строке. Если для этой программы нужны дополнительные ключи, вы должны тоже их передать.

Comment: Вариант с Process я пробовал всеми возможными способами. Сама программа, видимо, не принимает файл в виде аргумента, поэтому он и не подходит. А вот можно ли другими способами добиться открытия (утилита специальная, библиотека, код)?

Comment: @Николай: Ну так вот это вы выясните с самого начала: как именно принимает программа аргументы командной строки, и принимает ли вообще. Никакого общего способа нету, всё зависит лишь от желания программистов. Например, если программист вообще не написал код, заглядывающий в командную строку, то она, понятно, и не будет ни на что влиять.

Comment: Можно, конечно, на время через реестр поменять ассоциации файлов: сделать так, чтобы pdf ассоциировалось с данной программой, но потом необходимо восстановить исходные ассоциации, а в реестре написано просто "acrobat.exe", а не полный путь к программе.

Comment: Судя по всему никак не принимает, в этом вся загвоздка. В эту программу только drag drop'ом затащить pdf, тогда она его открывает.

Comment: @Николай: Ну вы бы поискали документацию к программе. Или спросили бы у авторов. Мы тут, не зная что за программа, вряд ли поможем. (Да и зная, всё же вопросы о формате командной строки тут на грани офтопика.)

Comment: @Николай даже если ассоциировать эту программу в реестре с типом файла, она его не откроет, если не умеет принимать путь к файлу из командной строки.  А если бы умела, то работал бы способ предложенный VlaD.

Comment: Проверил, действительно она не работает таким образом, так как это не было предусмотрено разработчиком. Спасибо, хоть проблема и не решилась.

Comment: @Николай: Не за что! Возможно, вы захотите работать с программой при помощи UI Automation. (Попробуйте [этот пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105).)