# Получить список элементов управления в программе

Tags: c#, winapi, viber

Не могу найти элементы управления в десктопном приложении Viber. Я использую Winspector, но он видит только сам процесс и контрол "Default IME". Мне нужно найти в нем кнопки, текст боксы итд. Например, приложение notepad++ в инспекторе просматривается нормально [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видны элементы формы и их классы.

Вот что у вайбера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для чего мне это нужно - я хочу программно определить вот этот элемент управления
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а дальше с помощью функций user32.dll проверять наличие данного элемента управления в окне.

Comment: А может там нет никаких Windows контролов?

Answer (score 1):

Есть много фреймворков, которые не используют нативные контролы Windows, и «рисуют» контролы на окне сами. Так делают, например, WPF и Qt. Десктопный Viber написан как раз на Qt.

Попробуйте использовать для ваших целей вместо этого [UI Automation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/10105). Например, вот такая программа у меня работает с контролами VLC, который написан на Qt:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // находим процесс
        var vlcProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("vlc").FirstOrDefault();
        // и его главное окно
        var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(vlcProcess.MainWindowHandle);

        // находим в нём меню
        var menuBar = window.FirstChildByType(ControlType.MenuBar);
        // в нём пункт "Медиа"
        var mediaMenu = menuBar.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(
                ControlType.MenuItem, "Медиа");
        // раскрываем его
        mediaMenu.GetPattern<InvokePattern>().Invoke();
        // даём приложению успеть раскрыть меню и создать подэлементы
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        // находим в меню "Медиа" пункт "Выход"
        var exitMenu = mediaMenu.FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(
                ControlType.MenuItem, "Выход");
        // и выбираем его
        exitMenu.GetPattern<InvokePattern>().Invoke();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

static class AutomationHelpers
{
    static public T GetPattern<T>(this AutomationElement element)
        where T : BasePattern
    {
        var pattern = (AutomationPattern)typeof(T).GetField("Pattern").GetValue(null);
        return (T)element.GetCurrentPattern(pattern);
    }

    static public AutomationElement FirstChildByType(
        this AutomationElement element, ControlType ct)
    {
        return element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ct));
    }

    static public AutomationElement FirstDescendantByTypeAndName(
        this AutomationElement element, ControlType ct, string name)
    {
        return element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Descendants,
            new AndCondition(
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ct),
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, name)));
    }

    static public AutomationElement FindWindowFrom(AutomationElement control)
    {
        var walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
        while (control.Current.ControlType != ControlType.Window)
            control = walker.GetParent(control);
        return control;
    }
}
```

---

Для просмотра контролов, которые поддерживают UI Automation, вам нужна [утилита `Inspect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Подскажите что делать в таком случае: инспектором я нашел нужный элемент управления http://f4.s.qip.ru/rg8it9vc.png, но какой тип выбирать вот здесь  var menuBar = window.FirstChildByType(ControlType.MenuBar); ? Его нет в списке типов ControlType.

Comment: @ArtemBalan: А `ControlType.Button` не пробовали?

Comment: не нашло ничего

Comment: @ArtemBalan: Странно. Тогда ищите по имени «Пополнить». Это как в `FirstDescendantByTypeAndName`, но уберите условие на тип.