# Имитация нажатия клавиши в другом приложении C#

Tags: c#

Допустим есть приложение microlab.exe, оно работает. Нужно сымитировать нажатие клавиши в этом приложении. Как это возможно сделать через C#? Объясню зачем мне это надо, чтобы не возникало вопросов. Программа microlab.exe не умеет сохранять информацию и её нужно вводить при каждом запуске ручками, а это длительный процесс. Думал записать команды в файл, чтобы оттуда они автоматически вводились.

Comment: P.S. Вопрос переместился в сторону поиска имени нужного контрола(button) и отправки события нажатия (click). Не понимаю как найти нужный контрол.

Comment: [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460756.aspx) - для поиска нужного контрола.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509662/10105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть нормальное решение: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx). Но это как стрелять из пушки по воробьям. Поэтому, если это твой первый и последний макрос в жизни, а нажатия клавиш вполне достаточно, то, возможно, тебе достаточно найти контол и [послать ему команду SendMessage](http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-send-text-to-notepad). Функции Send/PostMessage позволяют отправлять и отдельные нажатия (клавиатуры, мыши), но в этом случае тебе потребуется немножко помучиться с трансляцией для определенной раскладки клавиатуры. Ну, а если нужно быстро решить проблему, то можно взять тормозной, но готовый [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: А как мне найти нужный контрол (это кнопка)?