# Невозможно сделать реактивацию окна посредством Winapi - SetForegroundWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

```
int main() {

    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Безымянный — Блокнот");    
    if (!hWnd) ExitProcess(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        Sleep(2000);
    }


    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

При первом шаге цикла `notepad` активируется нормально.
Потом я делаю дективацию нотепада вручную (альт таб на какое то другое окно (**не консольное**, если запуск даного приложения происходит из консоли)).
Но на втором шаге `notepad` не активируется, а мигает в трее коричневым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать реактивацию возможной?

**Update**:
Прочтя ответы и доп. инфу попробовал сделать вот так.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc > 1) {
        HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Безымянный — Блокнот");
        if (!hWnd) ExitProcess(1);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        ExitProcess(10);
    }

    std::string app(argv[0]);
    app.append(" 1");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        system(app.c_str());
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
 }
```

И ведь задуманное работает! Неужели нельзя найти обходной путь и заставить работать все это в одном процессе. :(
Ведь с костылем все равно работает так или иначе.

Comment: Так и должно быть. "Никто кроме пользователя не имеет право выдвигать окно на передний план"

Comment: Как решить, очень нужно :) !!!

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Функция SetForegroundWindow имеет [определенные ограничения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks): фоновый процесс не может изменить активное окно, если в данный момент активно окно другого процесса. Процесс, владеющий активным окном, может передать это право другому процессу с помощью функции AllowSetForegroundWindow, но возможности принудительно "увести" активное окно у любого процесса нет.

Так как идея принудительно делать окно активным каждые 2 секунды выглядит довольно бессмысленной, возможно, вам на самом деле нужно что-то другое. Например, вызов [SetWindowPos](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) с флагом HWND_TOPMOST, который позволяет отображать окно постоянно поверх всех окон.

Comment: 2 секунды - это только для теста. А окно нужно делать активным , возможно через полчаса, час (то есть произвольное время). Действительно никак? Пишу маленькую тулзу для управления kodi через gamepad. Иногда коди может свернуться или декактивироваться, поэтому хотелось бы через геймпад активировать его обратно.

Comment: @ilw Именно активным, чтобы в него курсор вставал? Или просто показать на экране?

Comment: Чтобы курсор вставал конечно

Comment: Обновил вопрос!

Comment: @ilw Ваш обходной путь - это просто баг, который могут исправить в следующих версиях Windows. Открою секрет: в Win7 был более простой обходной путь, свернуть и развернуть окно, но в Windows 10 его исправили.

Comment: Угу, и найдется новый костыль и т.д.

Comment: @ilw способ сделать это без обходных путей на самом деле есть. Я же написал "*Процесс, владеющий активным окном, может передать это право другому процессу с помощью функции AllowSetForegroundWindow*". Ищите примеры инжекта кода в чужой процесс, они есть в том числе и на этом сайте. Готовый код я не буду писать, так как эта техника может использоваться при создании вирусов (строго говоря, я не вижу иной причины принудительно менять активное окно, кроме как намеренный вред пользователю).

Comment: А тут причину, что я описал вы не видите ? Какой же это НАМЕРЕННЫЙ вред пользователю?

Comment: @ilw У вас типичная проблема XY. Вам следовало бы спросить про *управления kodi через gamepad*, а не про активацию окна.

Comment: @vtt kodi - это только причина использования SetForegroundWindow и даный вопрос к управлению  kodi через gamepad не имеет никакого отношения. Kodi можно заменить - напр. Steam Big Picture, Mediaportal, тот же notepad напр. и т.д. Я мог бы не озвучивать причину - и вашего коммента вообще бы не было.

Comment: @ilw вы по какой-то причине полагаете, что принудительно вытаскивать окно на передний план с целью управления приложением это нормальная практика, но на самом деле это не так. Приложения, которые должны управляться программно, обычно реализуют для этого специальный функционал, который может работать и в фоне (например, в Google Chrome это Selenium headless web driver). Notepad поддерживает управление через UI Automation (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509662/ - здесь есть пример, правда для C#)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight мне не нужен ваш overkilled специальный функционал в данном конкретном случае, когда лишь нужно раз в неделю (возможно) поместить на передний план окно, если winda по какой то причине пошлет мне некий msxbox с ошибкой и дективирует коди, во время просмотра интересного кинца лежа на диване, после чего приходится подрывать свой зад и идти в потемках искать клаву с аль-табом. Только не советуйте мне покупать пс4 хотябы или linux устаналивать, ок ?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight далее, напр. если мне нужно управлять тремя медиапп - мне для каждого выискивать часами специальный функционал, или я лучше сделаю это https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo (пример 1), что я собственно и сделал. Работает для каждого приложения в моем случае - пару строчек кода, никакого вреда для пользователей. Теперь ждем, новую версию Windows где это будет исправляться ;)