# Взаимодействие с другим клиентским приложением

Tags: c#

Как можно взаимодействовать с другими клиентскими приложениями ?
Вот есть ПК программа, клиент-сервер и одним алгоритмом в ней постоянно приходится тыкать, внося различные данные. Вот как это можно автоматизировать ?

Comment: Отправляйте запросы сразу на сервер

Comment: @АндрейNOP Т.е. проанализировать сниффером трафик / посмотреть что уходит и т.д. ? Блин, тогда и многопоточно можно попробовать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP но там какие то злые клиенты - авторизация через USB ключи и т.д. Как бы не сдох ключ при попытке снифать xD Я думал просто кнопочки тыкать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509662/10105