# Как управлять приложением с графическим интерфейсом из другого приложения?

Tags: c++, c, автоматизация, системное-программирование

Предположим, что в Linux или Windows запущено приложение с графическим интерфейсом. Когда я нажимаю кнопку, происходит какое-то событие. Я хочу, чтобы другое приложение могло нажимать кнопки, вводить текст в поля, считывать текстовые поля и т. п., так же, как это делает пользователь.

Есть ПО для автоматизации действий браузера Selenium.

Как написать такую программу как Selenuim, только для других приложений, на языках программирования С и С++?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Графический процесс - и графический процессор - разные вещи.   Selenium - очень сложная программа. Для windows есть аналог - InternetExplorer.Application. Перед написанием подобной на selenium программы нужно определится с програмным интерфейсом. InternetExplorer.Application - использует ActiveX. Selenium - не юзал затрудняюсь сказать.

Comment: Я думаю будет проще посмотреть, как это делает autohotkey -https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235397/winapi-get-access-to-another-applications-controls

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону UI Automation - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509694/184217. | Уже упомянули AutoHotKey. Также смотрите AutoIt.

Comment: Единого универсального способа, боюсь, нет. Всё зависит от технологии (платформы, фреймворка), использованной для создания GUI. Например, если использовался WinAPI (или его обёртка WinForms), то можно посылать ему сообщения и таким образом управлять. Но это не будет работать с GUI, сделанном не на WinAPI. И т. п.