# Как имитировать нажатие клавиши в C#?

Tags: c#

Как имитировать нажатие клавиш в C#, например в Python это делает библиотека `PyAutoGUI`, как пример - `pyautogui.press('f1')`. Как такое реализовать в C#?

Comment: Задайте вопрос более развернуто. Вам надо нажимать кнопки внутри своего приложения? Отсылать нажатия активному окну стороннего приложения? Отсылать нажатие конкретному приложению в любом состоянии?

Comment: Есть NuGet пакет InputSimulator, но можно написать с нуля самому используя WinAPI метод `SendInput`.

Comment: Тут есть решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761169/send-keys-through-sendinput-in-user32-dll

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509662/10105